# Posterior Sampling in pymc3

Tags: python, pymc

1:23 PM (20 minutes ago)
Hi,

Trying to learn pymc3 (never learned pymc2, so jumping into the new stuff), and I suspect there is a very simple example/pseudocode for what I'm trying to do. Wondering if someone can help me out, as the past few hours I've not made much progress...

My problem is to sample from a posterior in a rather straightforward manner. Let "x" be a vector, "t(x)" be a function (R^n --> R^n map) of that vector, and "D" be some observed data. I want to sample vectors x from

P( x | D ) \propto P( D | x ) P(x)

Usual Bayesian stuff. An example of how to do this using NUTS would be spectacular! My main problem seems to be getting the function t(x) to work appropriately, and have the model return samples from the posterior (rather than the prior).

Any and all help/hints appreciated. In the mean time I'll continue to try stuff out.

Best,

TJ

Comment: What did *you* try so far?

Answer (score 2):

Your notation is a little confusing to me, but if I understand correctly, you want to sample from the likelihood (some function of the parameters and data) times the prior. And I agree - that's typical Bayesian stuff.

I think Bayesian logistic regression is a good example since we can't solve it analytically. Let's say our model is the following:

B ~ Normal(0, sigma2 * I)

p(y_i | B) = p_i ^ {y_i} (1 - p_i) ^{1 - y_i}

Where y_i is observed and p_i = 1 / (1 + exp(-z_i)) and

z_i = B_0 + B_1 * x_i

We'll assume sigma2 is known. After we load data into numpy arrays x and y, we can sample from the posterior with the following:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    #Priors
    b0 = pm.Normal("b0", mu=0, tau=1e-6)
    b1 = pm.Normal("b1", mu=0, tau=1e-6)
    #Likelihood
    yhat = pm.Bernoulli("yhat", 1 / (1 + t.exp(-(b0 + b1*x))), observed=y)
    # Sample from the posterior
    trace = pm.sample(10000, pm.NUTS(), progressbar=False)
```

To see a full example, check out this iPython notebook:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/jbencook/9295751c917941208349

pymc3 also has a nice glm syntax. You can see how that works here:

http://jbencook.github.io/portfolio/bayesian_logistic_regression.html